# Can Rakshasas do Yajnas?

Tags: yajna, rakshasa

Can Rakshasas do Vedic Yajnas?

Are there instances where Rakshasas were doing Vedic Yajnas, like in the Ramayana?

Comment: Yes prahalad all his life did yagna story in Raghavendra charitra tells about the power yagna kinda that he offered his oblation in Mahabharata there is fight between Arjuna and salva Raja He was not able defeat even using full power then he prayed Krishna. Krishna advices him to withdraw back some distance to move this salva out of this place where this yagna kunda

Comment: @PrasannaR Prahlada was not a Rakshasa. He was a Daitya Asura.

Comment: Dont u kniw meghnaad died while doing yajna?

Comment: @Partha Who died?

Comment: ravan's son meghnaad

Comment: @Partha How come he died? Because he did a Yajna?

Comment: he was killed by Lakshman

Comment: This meghnaad is pulastya great grandson so he his half brahmin

Comment: @PrasannaR thanks. i did not know something like half brahmin exists

Comment: @PrasannaR kindly let me know the source

Comment: Bali, who was the grandson of Prahlada was performing the ashwamedha sacrifice when Vamana entered the scene.

Comment: @user1952500 Bali was not a Rakshasa though; he was an Asura.

Comment: @Partha its all over there in Ramayana Rama performing prachita for killing Ravana but he didnt need to do that but to delude other he did that because he told every on that Ravana was pulastya rishi son

Comment: @PrasannaR thats ok.He was a learned brahmin rakshasa